# How to auto respond to CC only?

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a Mailbox to forward E-Mails to.

This Mailbox will automatically create a JIRA Issue in our JIRA Project. Sender will be assignee and persons in CC will be watchers.

To avoid questions about the status, we want an auto response, so colleagues know that we have received it.

The Outlook rule "Automatic response from Server" responds to the sender of the E-Mail, not to all, not to the persons in CC.

We want an auto response to all, including CC or better only to the persons in CC.

Can we create a VBA Script for that? Will the VBA Script be executed if my Outlook is offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop a VBA script for sending automatic replies according to your needs. But it can be executed only while the host application (Outlook in your case) is running.

The [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.

In the `NewMailEx` event handler you can create a response to the incoming email and send it back. You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)
- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)

Comment: Thank you very much, you lead me into the right way! Ragards Florian